# Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager is not recognized

Tags: powershell, azure

There is no alert for Backup vault in Azure. So, I followed Alert notification section in following article:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-manage-vms/

After login in Azure account using Azure powershell, I ran following command as mentioned in above article:

```
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager
```

The command is not recognized and giving following error. Any ideas? Thanks :)

Arnold..

```
-------
Switch-AzureMode : The term 'Switch-AzureMode' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script 
file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Switch-AzureMode:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
-------
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use azure CLI:

```
azure config mode arm
```

Answer (score 1):

Switch-AzureMode [was deprecated](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/wiki/Deprecation-of-Switch-AzureMode-in-Azure-PowerShell). 
You should be able to go without executing that commandlet as the product group enabled [side-by-side commandlets execution](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azps-1-0/). If that does not work, then try to check if your Azure Powershell is updated.